# On mouse over changing images

Tags: javascript

I want to make little slider with javascript and this is my code. HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="thumbs">
        <span id="img1"><img src="Anim/01.png" onmouseover="tofull(1)"></span><br>
        <span id="img2"><img src="Anim/02.png" onmouseover="tofull(2)"></span><br>
        <span id="img3"><img src="Anim/03.png" onmouseover="tofull(3)"></span><br>
        <span id="img4"><img src="Anim/04.png" onmouseover="tofull(4)"></span><br>
        <span id="img5"><img src="Anim/05.png" onmouseover="tofull(5)"></span><br>
        <span id="img6"><img src="Anim/06.png" onmouseover="tofull(6)"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="full">
        <img src="Anim/01.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript

```
function tofull(n){
    switch (tofull){
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/01.png'>";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/02.png'>";
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/03.png'>";
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/04.png'>";
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/05.png'>";
            break;
        case 6:
            document.getElementById("full").innerHTML = "<img src='Anim/06.png'>";
            break;
    }
}
```

Everytime I hover on the image in `#thumbs`, nothing happens. Can you tell me why? Idea is that if I hover on img1 I want to make print him in `#full`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `switch` on `n`.  You're `switch`ing on `toFull`

Use `switch (n)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your switch is using something different than what you are passing in. Also you can reduce some of your code by updating the node 'src' property of the image tag.

```
function tofull(n){
    //Select 'full' and get the image tag inside
    var imgEl = document.getElementById("full").childNodes[0];
    switch (n){
        case 1:
            imgEl.src = 'Anim/01.png';
            break;
        case 2:
            imgEl.src = 'Anim/02.png';
            break;
        //Continue the pattern
    }
}
```

If you ever have to change the name of 'full' you only have to update it in one place in your code